# 11db error in XCode C++

Tags: c++, xcode, structure

I'm following some C++ tutorials and have started experimenting with structures, however a test structure I built is not behaving as intended. I have tried running it a few times and all it outputs is (11db), and when I try rerunning it I get a window saying that the product is already running.

Here is the code...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

 struct Address {
    int streetNum;
    string streetName;
 };

 Address myHouse;
 myHouse.streetNum = 911;
 myHouse.streetName = "Inverness Street";

 cout << myHouse.streetName << endl;

 return 0; 

}
```

I would expect the output to be "Inverness Street". Why am I getting an error instead?

EDIT ** Bonus points for anyone who can tell me how to remove a missing file warning? I removed a useless file that was created as a means to find my way around creating different types of files, but since I deleted it I have had a warning in the file that it once shared a folder with.

Comment: Can't reproduce : http://ideone.com/Q1WPqd

Comment: As in... the code ought to be working fine? I guess it has something to do with the missing file then.

Comment: Since you mentioned xcode, my bet is that your output isn't "11db" but rather "(lldb)" in parentheses and in blue? If that's the case, do you have a breakpoint in your code somewhere before it gets to the `cout` statement?

Comment: You are correct, and yes- the line that contains the text "Address myHouse;" is a breakpoint.